# Return a list from recursive function

Tags: f#

I'm trying to return a list from a function, but I'm getting an error that says that an unit was expected instead. Also, I would like to know if this code appears to be structured correctly in general.

code:

```
    let rec calculateVariants (attList: NewProductAttributeInfo list) (activeCount: int) 
    (currentList: (int * NewProductAttributeInfo) list) =

    // group attribute list by category id
    let attGrouped = attList |> List.groupBy (fun x -> x.AttributeCategoryId)

    // define mutable list
    let mutable stageList = currentList

    // begin iteration
    for catId,details in attGrouped do
        for d in details do
            if activeCount = 0
            then stageList <- (activeCount,d) :: stageList

            let groupLength = attGrouped.Length
            if (activeCount + 1) <= groupLength
            then
                let selectCat,selectDetails = attGrouped.[activeCount + 1]
                selectDetails
                    |> List.filter (fun x -> 
                        stageList
                        |> List.exists (fun (x') -> 
                            not(x' = (activeCount,x))))
                    |> (fun x ->
                        match x with
                        | [] -> ()
                        | head :: tail -> 
                            stageList <- (activeCount, head) :: stageList
                            let currentCategory = activeCount + 1
                            calculateVariants attList currentCategory stageList
                            )
    stageList // <-- error Unit expected
```

Comment: the problem with `unit` is simply that none of your `if` expressions has an `else` branch and this is only allowed if the expression returns `unit` - the same is true for `for` loops ... and sadly no - both of these things are used in imperative programming and are not typical F# in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I came with. It works, but I'm sure it can be optimized quite a bit.  I have a duplicate issue that is solved with the Set.ofList function externally after this code runs, which I'm still working on.

```
type NewProductAttributeInfo = {
    AttributeId : string;
    AttributeCategoryId : string
}


let rec private returnVariant (curIdx: int) (listLength: int) 
    (attList: (int * NewProductAttributeInfo * NewProductAttributeInfo) list) 
    (curList: NewProductAttributeInfo list) =

    match curList with
    | x when x.Length = listLength -> curList
    | x -> 
        let attTup =
            attList
            |> List.filter (fun x' -> 
                                let idx1,att1,att2' = x'
                                idx1 >= curIdx && not(curList 
                                                        |> List.exists (fun x'' -> 
                                                                            x'' = att2'))
                            )
        let idx1,att1,att2 = attTup |> List.head
        let newList = curList @ [att2]
        returnVariant idx1 newList.Length attList newList


let rec calculateVariants (attList: NewProductAttributeInfo list) 
    (currentList: (int * NewProductAttributeInfo * NewProductAttributeInfo) list) =

    // group attribute list by category id
    let attGrouped = attList |> List.groupBy (fun x -> x.AttributeCategoryId)
    let (firstGroupCatId,firstGroupDetails) = attGrouped.[0]




    match currentList with
    | [] ->
        let rawVariants = [for nxt in 0 .. (attGrouped.Length - 1) do
                            if nxt > 0
                            then
                                // begin iteration
                                for d in firstGroupDetails do
                                    let _,det = attGrouped.[nxt]
                                    for det' in det do
                                        yield (nxt, d, det')
                        ]
        calculateVariants attList rawVariants
    | x ->
        let groupLength = x |> List.groupBy (fun (idx,d0,nxtD) -> idx)
                        |> List.length |> ((+)1)
        let sortedGroup = x |> List.sortBy (fun (x,y,z) -> x)
        if groupLength > 2
        then // below is the block that generates the duplicates
            [for att in sortedGroup do
                for attCompare in sortedGroup do
                    let idx1,att1,att2 = att
                    let idx2,attC1,attC2 = attCompare
                    if idx2 > idx1 && att2 <> attC2
                    then
                        let idString = 
                            returnVariant idx2 groupLength x [att1; att2; attC2]
                            |> List.map (fun nl -> nl.AttributeId)
                        yield String.concat "," idString
            ]
        else
            [
                for att in sortedGroup do
                    let idx1,att1,att2 = att
                    let idString = 
                            returnVariant idx1 groupLength x [att1; att2]
                            |> List.map (fun nl -> nl.AttributeId)
                    yield String.concat "," idString
            ]
```

Comment: I submitted my solution to code review, and a much more concise alternative was submitted. Here's the link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110316/find-unique-variants-of-a-product/110318#110318

Answer (score 2):

`if .. then .. else` should return the same type on both branches. If you omit `else` branch then compiler assuming that it returns `unit`. Add `else` branch returning list.

**Edit:**
Given your problem description, the easiest way would be something like this:

```
type NewProductAttributeInfo = {AttributeCategoryId: string; AttributeId: string}
let products = [ { AttributeCategoryId = "Size"; AttributeId = "S"};
                 { AttributeCategoryId = "Mat"; AttributeId = "Linen" };
                 { AttributeCategoryId = "Mat"; AttributeId = "Poliester" };
                 { AttributeCategoryId = "Color"; AttributeId = "White" };
                 { AttributeCategoryId = "Color"; AttributeId = "Green" };
                 { AttributeCategoryId = "Mat"; AttributeId = "Linen" };
                 { AttributeCategoryId = "Mat"; AttributeId = "Cotton" };
                 { AttributeCategoryId = "Mat"; AttributeId = "Poliester" };
                 { AttributeCategoryId = "Size"; AttributeId = "XL" } ]

let group list =
    list 
    |> Set.ofList // Provides uniqueness of attribute combinations
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun x -> x.AttributeCategoryId) // Grouping by CatId
    |> List.ofSeq

let res = group products
```

Result:

> ```
> val it : (string * seq<NewProductAttributeInfo>) list =
>  [("Color", seq [{AttributeCategoryId = "Color";
>                   AttributeId = "Green";}; {AttributeCategoryId = "Color";
>                                             AttributeId "White";}]);
>   ("Mat",
>    seq
>      [{AttributeCategoryId = "Mat";
>        AttributeId = "Cotton";}; {AttributeCategoryId = "Mat";
>                                   AttributeId = "Linen";};
>       {AttributeCategoryId = "Mat";
>        AttributeId = "Poliester";}]);
>   ("Size", seq [{AttributeCategoryId = "Size";
>                  AttributeId = "S";}; {AttributeCategoryId = "Size";
>                                        AttributeId = "XL";}])]
> ```

Comment: can you post an example based off of my code? I've added else stageList to all if statements including the match statement, but I am still getting the same error. Clearly I'm missing something simple here it seems.

Comment: As Carsten mentioned in the comment `for` loop also should return `unit`. It's hard to correct your example because it is not compiling

Comment: @user1206480: It would be helpful if you would describe what this function is supposed to do. Currently the logic is convoluted

Comment: I am trying to create a function that creates a sequence of a product and all of it's variations. For example a shirt product with attributes of size(S, M, L, XL, 2XL, etc.), Color(White, Black, Blue, etc.), Material(Cotton, Polyester). The result should have each unique variant such as [White; S; Cotton],[White; S; Polyester],[White; M;Cotton],[White;M;Polyester]...[Black;L;Polyester], etc.   I think the problem probably has to do more with my logic. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I should have clarified my problem a bit. A significant part of the problem is the fact that I won't know ahead of time how many attribute categories and the number of different attributes each category contains associated with a product. This data is retrieved from the database, so therefore I need to generate the sequence on the fly.

Comment: @user1206480 I don't see significant difference here. You have type `NewProductAttributeInfo` defined before you are calculating the result, isn't it?

Comment: @user1206480: If you'll provide `NewProductAttributeInfo` definition we could use it for a real prototype

Comment: Yes. It is a record defined as {AttributeCategoryId = string; AttributeId = string} .  When creating a product you have the option of creating any number of attributes and categories uniquely associated with that product. Subsequently, all attribute details are retrieved from the database for each product in which I must build from.

Comment: @user1206480 Corrected using your record definition

Comment: The initial database query doesn't return any duplicates in terms of AttributeId, so no worries there, but nevertheless once the attributes are grouped by category I then need to match combinations. So for example, if an attribute for white is returned, I then need to match white uniquely with every other attribute outside of its own category. (White, S, Cotton), (White,Xl,Cotton), (White,S,Polyester),(White,Xl,Polyester),etc. This would need to be done for each color returned or whatever ever category the attributes are grouped by. This would be the variants that the product is available in.